# Is the html form "action=" attribute still valid without a specific handler program?

Tags: html

i.e. -

```
<form action="http://192.168.1.20/form_action.asp" method="get">
```

vs. (**without a specific handler, still valid html?**)

```
<form action="http://192.168.1.20" method="get">
```

Creating a very basic custom web server on windows (will be c or C#).
Creates a page with one form and input field.

Can I bypass a separate form handler and just pull the value from the web server at some point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  `action` need only be a valid URL.  The path of that URL (everything after the server name, or in this case, IP) does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

The html is fine. You will want to mod apache (or whatever webserver you are using) to direct the action url/ip to the right place, though.